# Testflight - Build is there but not showing?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

So I just got an email telling me that my build has completed processing.
I go to iTunes connect and sure enough there it is. I go to add testers, and it asks me to input some contact info before it adds the testers.

Somewhere here the whole thing just stops working, so I reload the page and this is all I can see now:

[image]

My Build is there, it is the correct version, but I cant see it, or do anything with it, really weird. What is this?

Comment: Wait for some time it will come.

Comment: Been over 20 minutes. As I said, it was there after I got the email, then dissapeared after reload.

Comment: It can take nearly 30 minutes

Comment: For what? What happened? Why did it just dissapear while I was editing contact info? I would understand if there was delay  after I got the email, but it was there right after the email, then dissapeared

Comment: Is email says other then complete processing? Like missing some params for app or like that ?

Comment: Nope, just said it completed successfully, Not sure you understand. It worked fine after I got the email, THEN it dissapeared

Comment: Yeah! Nowdays it happens, same happen with my friend's account

Comment: Okay.. Thanks. God I hate everything apple. 100 steps (50% dont work first try) to upload an IPA. Meanwhile on Google play you drag and drop an APK and ur done...

Comment: & yes Google play store accept easily in compare to Apple

Comment: Still not there

Answer (score 0):

To create .ipa file i'm using Ad Hoc option. But for testing apple send an email like this ....

```
Missing beta entitlement - Your app does not include the beta-reports-active entitlement. If you intend to distribute this build via TestFlight for beta testing, please re-build this app with an App Store Distribution provisioning profile. Do not use ad-hoc profiles.

 After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

Regards,
The App Store team
```

Now i selected App Store option to create .ipa file. Now i uploaded the .ipa through application builder. Then only i'm getting my build in TestFlight. I think this will help you...

[image]